# Ag Grid: how to find a group row by id?

Tags: ag-grid

AgGrid API's getRowNode() returns *undefined* when I pass in id of a group node (works fine with non-group id). Is there a way to access group node?

Comment: where do you get the id of the group node from? I'd be better if you can post a minimal example here.

Answer (score 0):

there is no straight way to get the group node but if you have the child node using `params.api.getRowNode(rowIndex)` and if its level property is set to anything than 0 then its part of a grouping then you can call its parent object and check what is the
level of parent object,

if its not `level: 0` then you can go further up using parent object like this `params.api.getRowNode(0).parent.parent`